# Can't add Swift to PATH Linux

Tags: swift, linux, terminal

I'm running POP!_OS linux distro and want to run Swift on it. I found a tutorial on https://medium.com/@agavatar/open-source-swift-on-ubuntu-linux-cd00e697dff0
the problem is once I enter the line to add Swift to the PATH, I get this error:
"swift: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure with this little information, but it seem that you're missing dependencies. try:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev
```

EDIT: Ubuntu moved from libtinfo5 to 6 a while ago, you've installed the wrong swift version. you can get swift for unbutu 1804 here: `wget https://swift.org/builds/swift-4.2.1-release/ubuntu1804/swift-4.2.1-RELEASE/swift-4.2.1-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04.tar.gz`

Comment: Sorry. That didn't work. What kind of information would you need?

Comment: can you check if  "/usr/lib/libncurses.so.5" and "/usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5" exists please

Comment: Those files do not exist.

Comment: Just read the tutorial you sent, and the swift version you have installed is meant for ubuntu 1404, which uses libtinfo5, ubuntu 1604 ships with libtinfo6

Comment: you can try installing it with "sudo apt-get install libtinfo5" (tho I'm not sure if it'll work) or installing a version that uses libtinfo6

Comment: from that medium article:
 "We will need to download Swift packages from the official website. Package for Swift are available for Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 & 16.10. Mine OS is Ubuntu 14.04. Hence, download the swift package applicable to Ubuntu 14.04"